# assign json-serialized string into php array using json-decode

Tags: php, jquery, json

I would like to pass a string that has been serialized by JSON using $.ajax to an external php file to be assigned to a regular array.

Here is what I got so far which isn't showing 0th index of taskContent array.

**JQuery code:**

```
$(".json").click(function() {
            var allTaskArr = [];
            $('#appendTask .taskbox').each(function(index,domEle){
            //domEle == this
            allTaskArr[index] = $(domEle).val();
            });
        var allTaskStr = '{"taskContent":'+JSON.stringify(allTaskArr)+'}';

            $.ajax({
                url:'testjson.php',
                type:"POST",
                datatype:'json',
                data:allTaskStr

            });
 });
```

**PHP file:**

```
 $jsonContent = $_POST['taskContent'];
 $taskContent = json_decode($jsonContent,true);         
 echo $taskContent[0];
```

Comment: Have you made sure you are getting the json in PHP? what does print_r($taskContent); show?

Comment: use print_r($taskContent); in your php file to confirm that 0 index is there

Comment: Thanks Alex. I can't seem to get any output from my php file. With `alert(allTaskStr);` in the JQuery file, I'd get {"taskContent":["text-1","text-2"]}, then I'd assign text-1 and text-2 to index-0 and 1 of the taskContent array in the PHP file.

Comment: silly question, but it needs to be asked: does your PHP program start with `<?php`

Comment: what does `print_r($_POST)` look like?

Comment: @Spudley I'm getting 'Undefined Index: taskContent' message. The problem seems to be at decoding the json string that is in a form of {["taskContent":"text-1","text-2","text-3"...]}

Comment: `var_dump($taskContent);` at my php file returns NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> @Spudley I'm getting 'Undefined Index: taskContent' message.

The reason for this that PHP is not receiving a post variable named `tastContent`.

And the reason for this is that you are not sending the JSON correctly.

In the jQuery code, you are producing a JSON string, and then putting this in the `data` element of the ajax call. In fact, the `data` element is supposed to be given an object, not a json string; it encodes it to json itself, so if you give it json in the first place, the PHP program will receive a double-encoded string -- ie a json string which decodes to another json string.

So instead of this:

```
var allTaskStr = '{"taskContent":'+JSON.stringify(allTaskArr)+'}';
```

... you need to send the data as an object, like this:

```
var allTask = {taskContent:allTaskArr};
```

or just put it straight into the ajax call:

```
data : {taskContent:allTaskArr}
```

Hope that helps get you on the right track and explains what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks alot Spudley. I didn't know that the `data` element expects an object not a json string! Second thing i did to fix my problem was in my PHP file, I use `file_get_contents('php://input')` to receive the object.

Answer (score 1):

Disregard this post before this edit.

This is your issue:

```
var allTaskStr = '{"taskContent":'+JSON.stringify(allTaskArr)+'}';
```

Should be:

```
var allTaskStr = {"taskContent":JSON.stringify(allTaskArr)};
```

data:, expects an object and you are sending it a string.